# Option Clash for Hyperref Package with aastex class

Tags: hyperref, aastex

I am trying to load one document from overleaf to arxiv.
The code is as follows

```
\documentclass[twocolumn]{aastex63}
\begin{document}

a

\end{document}
```

And I am getting this error:

```
! LaTeX Error: Option clash for package hyperref.
```

In overleaf this works perfectly fine.

Comment: It works fine for me (using TeXLive 2020). What distribution are you using?

Comment: arxiv uses TeX Live 2016.

Comment: The error may be due to the document class ``aastex63``. Try uploading the class file in arxiv and see if the document compiles.

Comment: The class file was already uploaded.  I have now contacted the arxiv helpdesk and waiting for an answer.

Comment: aastex63 doesn't exist in texlive 2016. If you added it to your document it means that you are trying to new class with an old system and probably load internally old packages. That is bound to give problems.

Comment: arXiv adds their own `hyperref` configuration to submissions, which could lead to an option clash as you have encountered. You could remove `\usepackage{hyperref}` manually from `aastex63.cls` (lines 2101-2010) and see if that solves the problem, or alternatively use `\hypersetup` if you want to keep the link formatting.

Comment: The fatal error disappeared after I removed the `hyperref` package from the class and used `\hypersetup`  in the `<main>.tex`  after uploading the class. However no pdf is generated and I received the `undefined citations and references` warning.

Comment: Problem soved...After removing the `hyperref` package from the aastex63 class and used `hypersetup`  I realised that it didn't produce the pdf because of my internet browser (it is still a bit mysterious why). I switched from chrome to safari and it worked

Answer (score 0):

Overleaf's documentation has the following advice:
If the hyperref package is loaded by a document class or a package then it may not be feasible to change how hyperref options are loaded. One example is if you're using `\documentclass{mnras}`. In such cases you may have to prevent arXiv from injecting its hyperref commands. This can be done by adding a file to your project named `00README.XXX` and putting this line in it:
nohypertex

(from https://www.overleaf.com/learn/how-to/LaTeX_checklist_for_arXiv_submissions#Are_you_using_the_hyperref_package.3F )